# How can custom tab view be implemented using setCustomTabView method in SlidingTabColor sample?

Tags: android, tabs

I am using Android's SlidingTabColors sample in my application layout. I have three tabs initialized. Due to the default tab layout all the tabs have same layout. I have searched everything about setCustomTabView; but unable to get it implemented. I wanted to know where should i call this method? What statements are to be used?
I have used a switch statement in the onViewCreated method of the ContentFragment class. The code I have written in the onViewCreated method is posted below:

```
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
        int indicatorColor = args.getInt(KEY_INDICATOR_COLOR);
                switch (indicatorColor)
                {
                    case Color.RED:
{
SlidingTabLayout mSlidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
mSlidingTabLayout.setCustomTabView(R.layout.speed_test, R.id.hello1);
}
                    case Color.GREEN:
                        title.setText("Subject: " + args.getCharSequence(KEY_TITLE));
                    case Color.BLUE:
                        title.setText("Header: " + args.getCharSequence(KEY_TITLE));
                }
        }
```

The speed_test.xml file is posted below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:text="Hello"
android:id="@+id/hello1"
/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Edited:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
SlidingTabLayout.setCustomTabView(R.layout.speed_test,R.id.hello1);
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    SlidingTabsColorsFragment fragment = new SlidingTabsColorsFragment();
    transaction.replace(R.id.sample_content_fragment, fragment);
    transaction.commit();
}}
```

The error I am getting:

```
error:(139, 25) error: non-static method setcustomtabview(int,int) cannot be referenced from a static context
```

Answer (score 4):

First thing is to look at the [original source code](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabLayout.html) from google.
You can see that there is a method like this:

```
public void setCustomTabView(int layoutResId, int textViewId) {
    mTabViewLayoutId = layoutResId;
    mTabViewTextViewId = textViewId;
}
```

When you take a look at the method `populateTabStrip()` you can see that there is inflating a custom view (which you have set) when the `id` isn't 0

```
...
if (mTabViewLayoutId != 0) {
    // If there is a custom tab view layout id set, try and inflate it
    tabView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(mTabViewLayoutId, mTabStrip,
              false);
    tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(mTabViewTextViewId);
}
...
```

That mean that you must call the setCustomTabView() with the `Layout` as first parameter and the `TextView`  (which will displayed the text) as second parameter. Like

```
mSlidingTabLayout.setCustomTabView(R.layout.custom_x, R.id.item);
```

Don't set the layout to 0 (zero). The View will automaticly use the default `TabView` (which is a single `TextView`).

The layout, in my example, look like this and is called `custom_x.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Important! The method `setViewPager()` must called after `setCustomTabView()` in your Activity/Fragment.

```
mSlidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
mSlidingTabLayout.setCustomTabView(R.layout.custom_x, R.id.item);
mSlidingTabLayout.setViewPager(mViewPager);
```

Then you get a result like this:

[image]

It's also as [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3c04512ffc74a28a19e4) available.

Comment: Is it possible, using this way, to have a different image per tab?

Comment: Yes, of course. See theses gist: http://git.io/vO6hw
Explanation: The adapter hold all your drawable which will be displayed. These can be setup in the constructor. Also the adapter need a new method called `getPageDrawable(int position)` which returned the image which will be displayed. The `SlidingTabLayout` can now call these method and setup the ImageView.

Note: These classes are not tested. Maybe it's broken but the main idea is there ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll play with that advice :)

Answer (score 0):

Inside `SlidingTabLayout` the tabs layout is governed by `mTabViewLayoutId` and `mTabViewTextViewId`

just add a method:

```
 /**
 * Set the custom layout to be inflated for the tab views.
 *
 * @param layoutResId Layout id to be inflated
 * @param textViewId  id of the {@link TextView} in the inflated view
 */
public void setCustomTabView (int layoutResId, int textViewId) {
    mTabViewLayoutId = layoutResId;
    mTabViewTextViewId = textViewId;
}
```

and you are set to go. you should call this method @OnCreate of your activity, you can pass 0 as the first parameter for not to include Layout, and just pass the second param as for the layout id of some TextView. notice that you don't need to inlate the Views as you did

```
 @Layout/my_text_view
 <TextView
  android:layout_width="match_parent" 
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:text="Hello"
  android:id="@+id/hello1"
 />

 @onCreateView


 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

     mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(new SectionsPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager()));
    tabImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.tab_image_view);
    // Create the mAdapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    slidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    slidingTabLayout.setDividerColors(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
    slidingTabLayout.setSelectedIndicatorColors(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
    slidingTabLayout.setCustomTabView(0, R.layout.my_text_view);
}
```

Comment: I have called setCustomTabView method in onCreate of MainActivity. And I get this error. Error:(139, 25) error: non-static method setCustomTabView(int,int) cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: 'protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SlidingTabLayout.setCustomTabView(R.layout.speed_test,R.id.hello1);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            SlidingTabsColorsFragment fragment = new SlidingTabsColorsFragment();
            transaction.replace(R.id.sample_content_fragment, fragment);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }'

Comment: error:(139, 25) error: non-static method setcustomtabview(int,int) cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: why did you implement setCustomTabView as a Static method? it needs access to it's private members of course...

Comment: I have not. It indeed is giving error because the setCustomTabView method is not declared static.