# How to specify Custom Tab View without an image?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created a layout XML and called `setCustomTabView` in the right sequence and verified that it's pretty much as described here.

[How can custom tab view be implemented using setCustomTabView method in SlidingTabColor sample?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27676844/how-can-custom-tab-view-be-implemented-using-setcustomtabview-method-in-slidingt)

I don't want an image. I only want to control the text size. I want the default on a small phone, but twice the size on a tablet. The default is very small on a tablet. The app is used outdoors and visibility and large buttons is important. I have two "buckets" so far. The following examples are for the default.

If I use this xml layout, I only see the text for the first tab, and no colorizer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- Default sized TextView for tab title.
      This allows us to specify a larger one for tablets in layout-w720dp. -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tab_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="18dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Custom Tab Layout - text only]

If I add the xml for an image and provide a source, it works. If I leave out the source, the result is the same as for a layout with only a TextView.

```
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tab_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="18dp"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

[image: With an (unwanted) image]

In one of my experiments I increased the text size (very large) and without an image I got all four tab titles.

How can I replicate the default tab titles with only a TextView?
(I had a working solution where I detected the metrics at run time and doubled the text size, but I want to control this through different layout subfolders.)

I see that the default tabView is a simple, instantiated `TextView` and tabTitleView is equated to it. If I could do a `findViewById`on the TextView within my layout I could do the same. But attempts to do that resulted in a null TextView - probably because a ViewGroup is not yet established. But if I use my layout the child already has a parent and can't be used in the tab strip's addView().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tab_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:padding="16dp" />
```

Using the debugger (and looking at the source where the default tabView is created) I saw that gravity was 0x800033 for my TextView and 0x000011 for theirs. Changing the android:gravity and adding  the same padding as the default fixed it. I think `center` would also work. It's an alias for vertical|horizontal (1<<4|1<<0).

I also called `setAllCaps(true)` on the `tabTitleView` for consistency.